# flex column wont stretch to fill the column

Tags: css, flexbox

new to flex. Wonder why the the two div on the right won't take up the all the height space.

What I am trying to get here is to have a big column on the left while the right column will be divided by two row

css:

```
.card {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  margin:8% auto auto auto;
  width:450px;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  color: black;
}

.left-tile {
  flex: 3;
  background: #02A0E5; 
}

right-tile {
  flex: 2 1 50%;
  background: #FD6800;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.up-right-tile { 
 background: #D03324;
 flex: 2;
}

.low-right-tile {
  background: #FD6800;
  flex: 2;
}
```

html

```
.container
  .card
    .left-tile
      .card-content
        .quote-content
          ....
    .right-tile
      .up-right-tile
        .twitter-button
          ....
      .low-right-tile
        .new-quote
          ....
```

the actual code pen code is [here](http://codepen.io/ypan887/pen/PWWOqQ)

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing in your [codepen](http://codepen.io/ypan887/pen/PWWOqQ) is that you need to declare your `card` class as a `flex` container.

Like this:

```
 .card {
  position:relative;
  margin:8% auto auto auto;
  width:450px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

**Update**:

It seems that your concept is correct. Your error is just `right-tile` don't have `.`, then your code will definitely should work. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Jerred, thanks for the answer. I did add the flex class to the card container. So now left-tile and right-tile filled out the row direction. I made right tile a flex container in the column direction, but it's two child div won't fill up the remaining height even thought right-tile has the same height as left tile